# Laravel 5 : Why is my request->input returning null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to return the value of a checkbox within my laravel controller, but every time I request a input from a checkbox element in a form, it returns null.

My controller, retrieving the input of a element called Filter-Method.

[image: Retrieving the input of a element called Filter-Method]

Here I'm trying to request a input method called filter-method which is a checkbox.

My Route, since this function will execute on a button:

[image: since this function will execute on a button]

My Blade, where I'm trying to retrieve the result of my filter-method checkbox:

[image: where im trying to retrieve the result of my filter-method checkbox]

On line 38 I have a checkbox called filter-method, and when you click on the button on line 115 it should send a request to the controller where it would return a result but instead it returns null

[image: The resulting image]

Any ideas of why I'm returning null?

Comment: Add the code instead of images.Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You need to use a form to send the checkbox value to server. Currently you are using <a> tag with your link that will not send any value to server.

Answer (score 2):

You are not passing any parameter named filter-method. If you are posting values you should use post method.

Like following

```
Route::post('GetFilterByColumns','MentorController@FilterByValuesColoumns')
```

If you want to list data according to filter-method then try the following.

```
Route::get('GetFilterByColumns/{filter-method}','MentorController@FilterByValuesColoumns')
```

And in your **mentorlist.blade.php** page

change the href value according to route.

Answer (score 0):

This is very basic thing just use form instead of `<a>` tag. Every time you need to send input value to server you need to use `<form>` element. In image you have uploaded there is no `<form>` and you are using a `<a>` tag.

You need to do it like this

```
<form method="get" action="/getFilterBycolumns">
<input type="checkbox" name="filter-method">

// other input fields

// and then a submit button instead of <a>
<button class="your-class" type="submit"> Send</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add form to your blade around checkbox either with get or post method as per your requirement change route according to your form method

consider demo blade file

```
<form method="get" action="{{ url('GetFilterByColumns') }}" class="form-horizontal form-label-left"  id="">
   <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="filter-method" value="filter-method>Method</label>
   </div>
   <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Now you will get a checkbox value in contoller

Answer (score 0):

just use POST instead of GET if you are sending form values

Comment: How does this improve on the earlier answer which has more detail?